# AngularJS dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS newbie questions

- If I have an app with a dependency on a module `angular-carousel`

For Example:

```
angular.module('DemoApp', ['angular-carousel'])
```

How do I give my controller access to the functions within 'angular-carousel' like 'nextSlide', 'prevSlide' etc so I can programmatically control the navigation?

Comment: You have to use dependancy injection, more about it here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value of selected image by `<div rn-carousel-indicators ng-if="slides.length > 1" slides="slides" rn-carousel-index="carouselIndex"></div>` Carousel Index is the index of the selected image.

Read the [documentation](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel) Everything you would need should be there

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clearer. I was just using angular-carousel as an example. My question is more basic: Given any module as a dependency, how can I access the methods within that module in my controller?

Comment: @AfrozLazemi It totally depends. Sometimes, you may not have to use any method in the  controller. You just have to use the specified directive in your HTML. That directive is already inbuild in the module you included. Everything will be taken are of by that. In some cases though, when you require some methods or properties to be accessed in your controller, they can be bound using the HTML. As you can see we are binding the slides property in the HTML. This would pass the slides property from your scope to the directive. Then sometimes you can also inject dependencies in your controller.